# Longest path between all pairs in a DAG

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs, floyd-warshall

I was trying to find the longest path between all pair of nodes in an acyclic directed graph.My question is will Floyyd Warshall give correct answer if I make the following initial condition in the adjacency matrix ?

1. Adj[i][j]=0 if i=j
2. Adj[i][j]=-1*INF if i!=j and there is no edge between node i and j
3. Adj[i][j]=w[i][j] otherwise, where w[i][j] is weight of edge between node i and j

The weights of edge can be positive and negative.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why don't you use dynamic programming instead? It is more efficient in terms of time and space complexity and its correctness is easier to prove(I'm not sure if you method is correct).

Comment: @user2040251 yes I can but i want to know the above :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Floyd Warshall can give a correct answer for your problems, can be proved like using Floyd Warshall to find the shortest path between all pairs in graph.
Or you can multiply each edges with (-1), and solve your problem like finding the shortest path between all pairs, then multiply your result with (-1).

But you can sort graph topologically, then use dynamic programming to calculating, which has complexity is max(|E|,|V|) instead of |V|^3 of FW.

Comment: It's important to note this only works with **acyclic** graphs. If the graph may contain a cycle, it's an NP hard problem.